# Amazon Fire 7 Tablet

Tags: kindle

I have purchase a new tablet. Its a Amazon Fire 7, new generation 2017. Can I install ubuntu on my new Amazon Fire 7 tablet? And how.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, there is not. Ubuntu is (IIRC) not supported for mobile devices anymore (not even at all for tablets). I would not recommend trying to install desktop Ubuntu on it either due to desktop Ubuntu not being optimized for ARM tablets.